# Full-text search CONTAINSTABLE

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have a question regarding a CONTAINSTABLE function. I would like to find everything that ENDS WITH the search string.

I can use the * to find everything that starts with the searchvalue, but I want an equivalent for the % sign in the SQL LIKE function.

What I want: find everything that ends with 123, so as searchvalue, I could use "*123" in my CONTAINSTABLE function. But that doesn't work..

If I want all results starting with 123, I use "123*", and that works well.

But what's the equivalent for --> LIKE %123 ?? it isn't "*123" in the CONTAINSTABLE function.
What is it then?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400/how-do-you-get-leading-wildcard-full-text-searches-to-work-in-ms-sql

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL Server fulltext search does NOT support searching for expression with a leading "%" - tried that myself, but it's just not supported.

You can search for CONTAINS( "expression%" ) - but **not** for CONTAINS( "%postfix" ).

Marc

Comment: Thanks Marc,

Is there a solution which uses full-text search for a searchvalue "ends with"?

Comment: No, not at this time, unfortunately. Your only option would be to use another product (like Lucene.NET) instead of SQL Server's built-in fulltext search

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work-around:

I stored the full-text column twice.  Once in normal form, the other in reverse.  Looking for all values that contained "china", I issues the following query:

```
select * from MyBigTable 
where TheNormalColumn   contains ('"china*"')
   or TheReversedColumn contains ('"anihc*")
```

It is twice as much work, takes up twice as much space, but it works.