# CONTAINS sql function doesn't match underscores

Tags: sql, contains

I have some table 'TableName' like Id,Name:

```
1 | something
2 | _something
3 | something like that
4 | some_thing
5 | ...
```

I want to get all rows from this table where name containes 'some'.
I have 2 ways:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Name like '%some%'
```

Result is table :

```
1 | something
2 | _something
3 | something like that
4 | some_thing
```

But if I use CONTAINS function

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE CONTAINS(Name,'"*some*"')
```

I get only

```
1 | something
3 | something like that
```

What should I do to make CONTAINS function work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ca-co_15.htm

If you read this article you will see that * means prefix this means that word must start with this, but like means the word contains key phrase.

Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: I know what prefix * stands for, I use it to get strings like 'something like that' or 'this is something'. I'm interesting in how to get string with underlinings using CONTAINS function.

Comment: then you must add one more CONTAINS function with parent with underline SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE CONTAINS(Name,'"*some*"') OR CONTAINS(Name,'"*_some*"')

Comment: If I use it I can get strings like 'something', '_something', but can't get 'some_thing'. I want get all string with word 'some', so you way is not panacea.

Comment: the do it with like operatot or just add OR CONTAINS(Name,'"*some_*"') to previous expression i prefer using like

Comment: Thank you, I try it but  CONTAINS(Name,'"*_some*"') don't match 'this_something' string, only '_something'. On the one hand CONTAINS work faster then Like statement, on the other CONTAINS doesn't match string I wish, so you are right I better use Like.

Comment: I read some where on the internet that if the column you filter with like has index on it and the like filter has % only on right then the index works and like is faster. CONTAINS(Name,'"_some"') OR like 'some%' might be faster then just like '%some%' but you have to test this.

Comment: Thank you answer, but I need '%some%' statement.

Answer (score 2):

The last time I looked (admittedly SQL Server 2000) `CONTAINS` didn't support wildcard matching at the beginning of words, only at the end. Also, you might need to check your noise files to see if the "_" character is being ignored.

Also see

[How do you get leading wildcard full-text searches to work in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400/how-do-you-get-leading-wildcard-full-text-searches-to-work-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE CONTAINS(Name,'some')
```