# looking for word parts with full text search in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

how do I find, with full text search all words that match '*ability*' mask, like "suitability" and "dependability", etc? is that possible?

Comment: Here is how to do it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962776/using-full-text-search-in-order-to-find-partial-words-sql-server-2008

Comment: Here's the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962776/using-full-text-search-in-order-to-find-partial-words-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible out of the box. Apparently wildcards do not work. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664387/sql-server-full-text-search-leading-wildcard) for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem, and there didn't seem any nice way round it but to also chain OR WHERE x LIKE "%term%" searches in each individual field.