# Using Full-Text-Search in order to find partial words (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm trying to build a facebook like search for my software.

I'd like to query the table customers.

I've set up a FULLTEXT Index and tried the next query

```
SELECT * FROM Customer where CONTAINS(*,'*ann*')
```

The query does return all the customers named Ann, but it doesn't return all the customers name Anne.

Is there a way to create prefix search on SQL Server 2008 using FTS?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem.
The query should be:

```
select * from Customers where contains(*, '"ann*"')
```

The quotes are the important part.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this solution only works for prefixes like in `'"ann*"'`. It doesn't work for suffixes like in `'"*ann*"'` or `'"ann"'`.