# Address search in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, search, database-design

I have table that contains five million addresses as strings.
There is a user interface that allows you to search by address and it is implemented in the simplest possible way - using the `LIKE` syntax with wildcards at the both ends of the searched string.
However this approach is really slow (especially when search result has to be sorted by some criteria).
I thought of using fulltext search as it would be much faster but it limits users and I dont want it since most search queries contain just part of word.
Addresses also can be abbreviated.

What can I do? How could I implement the address search to be more efficient but without sacrificing much of the user experience.

**Edit**
Ive just read that I can actually use a wildcard at the end of the string when performing `match against` fulltext search.
So if i store the reversed address maybe I can do prefix wildcard fulltext search.
But will it be faster and how much? Are there some benchmarks? I couldn find one.

Comment: yes, I do but it is still not fast

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). The `LIKE` operator in SQL is very inefficient, especially when you have that many records.

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned Fulltext in his question, and why he fears it may not be applicable to his needs.  `LIKE` can be extremely efficient, but only where the pattern can be matched against an index prefix.

Comment: That he did; I missed that part. However, I'm not sure how the full-text search limits the user in his case.

Comment: Nor me.  But it certainly won't help when "*most search queries contain just part of word*".

Comment: @eggyal You can construct your full-text search to search parts of the words using `"` and `*`. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962776/using-full-text-search-in-order-to-find-partial-words-sql-server-2008) has a good example, although its MSSQL, not mySQL.