# sometimes mysql fulltext search doesn't return any results when it should be

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search, match-against

My MySQL database table contains 2510 records. When I try to search for a string in a column, using fulltext search, sometimes, I don't get any results. Just an empty html table.

For example, I'm searching for the author 'Peter Schmidt'. If I search for 'Peter' I'll get the right author, but if I search for 'Schmidt', the html table shows other authors, but not the right one. The author's column consist of 'surname, name' (Schmidt, Peter).

This is a piece of my code:

```
    $author = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['author']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE MATCH(author) AGAINST ('$author' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$query) {
        echo 'We cannot find the author you are searching for. Please try again.';
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" class="back" style="margin:0;" title="Go back">&raquo; Go back</a>';

    } else {
        echo '<p>These authors match your query:</p><table>'
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo '<tr><td>'.$result['author'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>'
    }
```

What causes this issue?

Comment: What happens when you type in `Schmidt,` into your search query?  Wondering if the comma is getting in your way.

Comment: I still don't get the right author, just the others.

Comment: Try the 'like' operator

Comment: I think that the problem is the comma. Just try to add a * after the $autor: AGAINST ('$author*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) and see what happends

Comment: Okay, next question is, does `Schmidt` appear in more than half of the records.  I wouldn't imagine it does, but I have to ask.

Comment: I've already tried to use the like operator, but there's no difference.

Comment: @Crackertastic No, it doesn't. Just a few authors have that surname.

Comment: "author LIKE 'Schmidt%'" is not working? Well, probably there is another problem.

Comment: Once try after using trim, I mean trim the get data and try.

Comment: @Monte both 'like' or 'match-against' work. But they don't show me the right author.

Comment: Design related question - Is there a reason that the surname and name fields are not separate fields?  It would make life easier using the `FULLTEXT` indexes.

Comment: @Crackertastic I know, I got the MS access database from a relative and I had to transfer it to a mysql-database.

Comment: Did Monte's suggestion of using the wildcard in your `AGAINST` work?

Comment: When you get the results for "Schmidt" search, there is no "Schmidt, Peter" in any of these? It's pretty strange. What if you search for "Schmidt, Peter"?

Comment: @Crackertastic No, if I use '$author*', it still doesn't give me the right result.

Comment: Print Schmidt from database and search input in hexadecimal. They might be different.

Comment: @Monte No, there isn't. If i search for 'Schmidt, Peter', I still get an empty html table.

Comment: @Steven Check FULLTEXT index definition in your table

Comment: @SaiPhani the column author has a FULLTEXT index type.

Comment: try if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962776/using-full-text-search-in-order-to-find-partial-words-sql-server-2008) might help you

Comment: @SaiPhani That doesn't work. If I try that, the query doesn't even work.

Comment: I have a quick question: If you run `SELECT * FROM books WHERE MATCH(author) AGAINST ('+Peter' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`, does it find that record ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA It does, but not if I use '+Schmidt'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to use BOOLEAN MODE matching if you dont know [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) for it. As also check for proper encoding in php/mysql connection:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_client = utf8;");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = utf8;");
mysql_query("SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci;");
$author = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['author']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author LIKE '%$author%'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$query) {
    echo 'We cannot find the author you are searching for. Please try again.';
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" class="back" style="margin:0;" title="Go back">&raquo; Go back</a>';
} else {
    echo '<p>These authors match your query:</p><table>'
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$result['author'].'</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>'
}
?>
```

Comment: I've tried to use the like operator, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Please dump table information with command: mysql> show table status where Name='table_name';

Comment: So, collation for this table is utf8_general_ci. Please check you have defined php to use utf8 - add mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); somewhere in beggining. As also check mysql connection for proper collation.

Comment: Name: books, 
Engine: MyISAM, 
Version: 10, 
Row_format: Dynamic, 
Rows: 2510, 
Avg_row_length: 233, 
Data_length: 586680, 
Max_data_length: 281474976710655, 
Index_length: 194560, 
Data_free: 0, 
Auto_increment: 2512, 
Collation: utf8_general_ci