# SQL Contains not working on full text index with preceding *

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, fulltext-index, full-text-catalog

```
select top 10 * from table where contains(*,'"abc*"')
```

works and returns 6 rows

abcdef

abcd

abcd

abcde

ABCDEFGH

ABCDEFG

```
select top 10 * from table where contains(*,'"*bc*"')
```

returns no records found.

Does anyone know how I can get the '"****bc****"' function to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading wildcard searches will exclude the use of any index... including full-text indexing.

So `"*bc*"` isn't compatible with full-text indexing... and a non-full-text search such as `LIKE '%bc%'` will result in a full-table scan.

Related Questions:

[SQL Server Full Text Search Leading Wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664387/sql-server-full-text-search-leading-wildcard)

[How do you get leading wildcard full-text searches to work in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400/how-do-you-get-leading-wildcard-full-text-searches-to-work-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select top 10 * from table where contains(*,'%bc%')
```

or

```
select op 10 * from table where COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%bc%'
```