# too slow sql server select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql server table Bookchapter with about ~ 140.000 rows, FullContent field is nvarchar (max) with long content inside.

```
 SELECT     COUNT(Id) AS Expr1
    FROM         dbo.BookChapter
    WHERE     (FullContent LIKE '%xxx%')
```

without Where clause, it runs fine but with Where Clause involved with Fullcontent, sql server always cause timeout expired

I have no idea how to get it to work.

Comment: try changing your LIKE method to a CONTAINS method

Comment: oy...`LIKE` is an expensive operation.  A fulltext index will help...

Comment: `FullContent` is alot of data and slow since need to scan the all field , is there any option of refine the `like` to something faster ? what can you share about what you are looking for ?

Comment: You are searching for a substring within 140,000 *chapters* worth of text?  You need to look into [full text indexing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879306.aspx).

Comment: thanks, i'll try fulltext indexing.

Comment: Fultext indexing also doesn't work when using leading wildcards see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsearch/thread/02ebc411-0fcf-40ee-9963-3f64ed4409bb or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664387/sql-server-full-text-search-leading-wildcard