# Full-text search with wildcard

Tags: search, full-text-search

I have a table with full text search enabled. But I can't get query the table using wildcard.

**select * from products where contains(Description, 'Computer')** returns rows with the word "Computer"

**select * from products where contains(Description, 'Compute*')** [replace "r" with "*"] returns nothing

What's going on?

Comment: which database server you are using?

Comment: Which SQL engine are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get leading wildcard full-text searches to work in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400/how-do-you-get-leading-wildcard-full-text-searches-to-work-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server, add double quotes around the wildcarded expression like so

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE contains(Description, '"Compute*"')
```