# Wildcard in ContainsTable of full-text search

Tags: sql-server

I have a question what's different between "blah" and "blah*" in the containstable? 
below is my context.

```
create table testWildcard(pk int identity constraint twpk primary key, displayName varchar(100))
GO
create fulltext catalog test12 as default
GO
create fulltext index on testWildcard(displayName) key index twpk
GO
insert into testWildcard(displayName) values('blahBlahBlah')
insert into testWildcard(displayName) values('blah<bold>Blah</bold>Blah')
insert into testWildcard(displayName) values('blah Blah Blah')
GO
```

when use "blah*" as keyword to search, the result is 3 records.

```
select * from testWildcard t 
inner join CONTAINSTABLE(testWildcard, *, '"blah*"', LANGUAGE 1033) as w on t.pk=w.[Key]

    results:
            pk  displayName                  Key RANK 
            1   blahBlahBlah                 1  16
            2   blah<bold>Blah</bold>Blah    2  48
            3   blah Blah Blah               3  48
```

when use "blah" as keyword to search, the result is 2 records.

```
select * from testWildcard t 
inner join CONTAINSTABLE(testWildcard, *, '"blah"', LANGUAGE 1033) as w on t.pk=w.[Key]

resuts:
            pk  displayName                  Key RANK 
            2   blah<bold>Blah</bold>Blah    2  48
            3   blah Blah Blah               3  48
```

Then I use system function sys.dm_fts_parser to analyse the keywords, they don't have any difference. I google it but I still cannot find the proper answer.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"blah"', 1033, 0, 0) 
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"blah*"', 1033, 0, 0)  
result:
keyword             group_id    phrase_id  occurrence   special_term  display_term expansion_type source_term
 0x0062006C00610068 1           0          1            Exact Match        blah       0             blah
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Star(*) in FTS is used for wild card the same concept as normal query.

So when you search `blah`, it search the word comes with `blah`.
When you use `blah*`, it search the word starting with `blah` whatever written after that.

If you search with `*blah`, it search where the end word  `blah`.

Now your question is why `blahBlahBlah` entry not comes in first search, the reason as per [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) it is not any of this: (means FTS only search which is known word in simple term, not any word which we create)

> CONTAINS can search for:
>
> ```
> A word or phrase.
>
> The prefix of a word or phrase.
>
> A word near another word.
>
> A word inflectionally generated from another (for example, the word drive is the inflectional stem of drives, drove, driving, and driven).
>
> A word that is a synonym of another word using a thesaurus (for example, the word "metal" can have synonyms such as "aluminum" and "steel").
> ```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879300%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

[How do you get leading wildcard full-text searches to work in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400/how-do-you-get-leading-wildcard-full-text-searches-to-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: So does this mean Full-Text is not a good choice for text containing weird (arbitrary) product names?

Comment: yes, ideally it search dictionary word. above comment from MSDN, where fts search on phrase.

Comment: As you can see in the **More Info** part of your second offered link, `*blah` doesn't  work at all while `blah*` does.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the list of contents of the index using `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords`

```
SELECT display_term, column_id, document_count
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords(DB_ID('DatabaseName'), OBJECT_ID('testWildcard'))
```

You'll see еркуу words: blah, blahblahblah, bold.

That means that space, `<` and `>` "break" a word when creating the full-text index.

Now, when you search by "blah" `CONTAINS` returns only strings that contain word `blah` exactly.
And when you add wildcard `*` and so search by "blah*" `CONTAINS` returns all strings that contain words, beginning with `blah`.