# SQL Server Efficient Search for LIKE '%str%'

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

In Sql Server, I have a table containing 46 million rows.
In "Title" column of table, I want make search. The word may be at any index of field value.

For example:

**Value in table: BROTHERS COMPANY**

**Search string: ROTHER**

I want this search to match the given record. This is exactly what LIKE '%ROTHER%' do. However, LIKE '%%' usage should not be used on large tables because of performance issues. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Do you have full text index? Try posting table structure and use "Contains" for searching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I don't know your requirements, your best approach may be to challenge them. Middle-of-the-string searches are usually not very practical. If you can get your users to perform prefix searches (`broth%`) then you can easily use Full Text's wildcard search (`CONTAINS(*, '"broth*"')`). Full Text can also handle suffix searches (`%rothers`) [with a little extra work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/124502/65775).

But when it comes to middle-of-the-string searches with SQL Server, you're stuck using LIKE. However you may be able to improve performance of LIKE by using a binary collation as explained in [this article](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2015/01/20/optimizing-substring-search-performance-in-sql-server/). (I hate to post a link without including its content but it is way too long of an article to post here and I don't understand the approach enough to sum it up.)

If that doesn't help and if middle-of-the-string searches are that important of a requirement then you should consider using a different search solution like Lucene.

Comment: You're right. SQL Server has no equivalent of pg_trgm - trigram search module from PostgreSQL. It's possible to write own trigram serach mechanism, but it uses complex queries and procedures: https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search. Pg_trgm is already optimised and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Add [Full-Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms142571.aspx) index if you want.

You can search the table using `CONTAINS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONTAINS(TableColumnName, 'SearchItem')
```

Comment: No. Because if you search in google then you will find lots of resources about this. Please don't misunderstand.

Comment: Full text search cannot do what I want. Because Full Text Search parses the words and does NOT search string in any words.

Comment: Link is broken...