# How to convert LIKE to CONTAINS in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

**This is a query using 'LIKE':**

```
  SELECT JoinedColumnInfo FROM [dbo].[ImportedData]
  WHERE CategoryId = 11131700
  AND  JoinedColumnInfo LIKE  '%usb%'
```

**The 'LIKE' result table is:**

```
1.F5TYEU 2815124 KOSS cs100usb Double Sided Comm Headset USB, Noise Cancelling Microphone Wired

2.PODCASTUDIOUSB BEHRINGER Studio PodCast Kit - Includes Microphone, Mixer and Headphones

3.NUYVSRB 79X3419cs100usb KOSS Double Sided Comm Headset USB, Noise Cancelling Microphone
```

**And this is the same query using 'CONTAINS':**

```
   SELECT JoinedColumnInfo FROM [dbo].[ImportedData]
   WHERE CategoryId = 11131700
   AND  CONTAINS  (JoinedColumnInfo,   '"usb*"')
```

**The CONTAINS result table is: (2 results)**

```
1.F5TYEU 2815124 KOSS cs100usb Double Sided Comm Headset USB, Noise Cancelling Microphone Wired

3.NUYVSRB 79X3419cs100usb KOSS Double Sided Comm Headset USB, Noise Cancelling Microphone
```

**In the CONTAINS query** I don't get the record **number 2** why?
how can I convert from 'LIKE' to 'CONTIANS' and get the same results?

Comment: Can you provide a sample table and output?

Comment: Hi @Tejas I added a sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some fundamental differences in how LIKE and CONTAINS work, the most important is that you need an existing full-text index on the column when using CONTAINS.

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> CONTAINS can search for:
>
> - A word or phrase.
> - The prefix of a word or phrase.
> - A word near another word.
> - A word inflectionally generated from another (for example, the word drive is the inflectional stem of drives, drove, driving, and driven).
> - A word that is a synonym of another word using a thesaurus (for example, the word "metal" can have synonyms such as "aluminum" and
>     "steel").

LIKE on the other hand uses pattern matching to find simple string matching to find the value you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @Michael Tobisch, in other words, I can't use CONTAINS to search for a substring inside a larger string? I can only search for a word?

Comment: It is listed what you can search for. Follow the link above and read the documentation about full-text indexing, please. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400/how-do-you-get-leading-wildcard-full-text-searches-to-work-in-sql-server) is helpful as well.